# I am searching for a rule on the use of was and were preceded by if

Tags: english

I was taught that in a "subjective phrase" such as one beginning with "If I," you should use were, not was.
If true, I see it misused every day by many people and it is annoying.
Please set me straight or advice where I may find the answer.
Thank you

Comment: It is a language-specific question, [answered many times](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15726/if-you-were-or-if-you-are) at ELL.SE

Comment: You can find a description of the *was-were* contrast in Huddleston & Pullum's 2002 *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*.  When looking it up, please note that they refer to it as an irrealis form, not a past subjunctive form.  (They explain their choice of terminology, but the important thing is the description, not what you call it.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you what is correct (since I'm a descriptive linguist), but judging from what I use and hear from others, I think you use "were" in a counterfactual when the style is formal, and "was" when either the style is informal or you don't wish to commit yourself about the truth of the antecedent clause. E.g., "If I were a prescriptive linguist, I'd tell you to use "were" if you were being formal and I was actually not a prescriptive linguist."

Answer (score 0):

I speak that dialect, where that distinction is made, though many people don't and they just use "was". It *is* pointless to object to an established dialect that others speak. Since this is something that you were taught and don't natively know the answer to, you should let this go and focus on situations where "creative" stretching of language leads to actual confusion.

So in my dialect, it's not associated with formality, it's just there. There's a whopping difference between "If I was rude..." and "If I were rude...", where the former can felicitously be followed by "I apologize" and the latter can be felicitously followed by "I would have have objected to your silly comment". In the first case, you don't know if you were being rude, and in the latter case you know (believe) that you were not being rule, which is what counterfactuality is about.

{Addendum}
There is more to it than mere conterfactuality. I find "If I was/were you, I'd exit here" both acceptable, even though I clearly am not you. The difference is that in this case, I'm not strongly asserting that my being you is counter to fact, whereas in "If I were rude..." cases, the point is deny that you are being rude. I'll have to think over the pragmatic nuances of the two constructions in that context.